# Query partition style via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Normally I have been checking disk information via my script. I want to add PartitionStyle column inside my output like below. How can I do that ?

My output:

```
Server Name   Drive Letter
-----------   ------------
server01        C:          
server01        D:          
server01        F:          
server01        K:
```

My desired output:

```
Server Name   Drive Letter  PartitionStyle
-----------   ------------  ------------
server01        C:               MBR
server01        D:               MBR
server01        F:               GPT
server01        K:               GPT
```

Script:

```
$Servernames = "localhost"

$DiskReport = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk `
-ComputerName $Servernames | Where {$_.Drivetype -eq "3"}  `
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#create reports
$DiskReport | 
Select-Object @{Label = "Server Name";Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
@{Label = "Drive Letter";Expression = {$_.DeviceID}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below

```
Get-Disk | ForEach-Object {
    $disk = $_
    Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DiskName = $disk.FriendlyName
            PartitionStyle = $disk.PartitionStyle
            DriveLetter = $_.DriveLetter
        }
    }
} | Where-Object { $_.DriveLetter } | Format-Table DiskName, DriveLetter, PartitionStyle
```

It did tell me on my PC which drive is in which type.

My PS version is

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting an error message.   `Get-Partition : No MSFT_Partition objects found with property 'DiskNumber' equal to '4'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:3 char:5
+     Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number | ForEach-Object {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (4:UInt32) [Get-Partition], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DiskNumber,Get-Partition`

Comment: 4      Generic- SD/MMC CRW                                    2012062914345300                 Healthy              No Media                      0 B RAW